# Is there another way to write string to datetime SQL query?

Tags: sql, firebird

I have a problem with date time format in database. It has format dd.MM.yyyy. I want to change this format to yyyy-MM-dd. I have a query that works perfectly in SQL compiler, but it doesn't work in DBeaver Firebird 3 database. When I try to run this I get following error:

> SQL Error [335544634] [42000]: Dynamic SQL Error; SQL error code =
> -104; Token unknown

I'm presuming that Firebird 3 doesn't implement some SQL functions. So my question is, how can I write this query differently?

```
SELECT SDC_TIME_SERVER_TIMEZONE 
FROM SDC_INVOICES 
WHERE DATE(substr(SDC_TIME_SERVER_TIMEZONE, 7, 4) || '-' || substr(SDC_TIME_SERVER_TIMEZONE, 4, 2) || '-' || substr(SDC_TIME_SERVER_TIMEZONE, 1, 2)) BETWEEN DATE('2022-01-01') AND ('2022-04-08')
```

Comment: I don't think it is an issue with Firebird, rather with Sqlite. Sqlite has a different syntax than other SQL servers. Also, Sqlite dosen't handle dates very well. I think they are stored as strings. Can you share what your datatable looks like ?

Comment: My date field look like this 
07.04.2022. 11:06:51, 
and I need it to look like this 2022-07-04 11:06:51, so I can create valid SQLite query. So I need to create reordered string.

Comment: I removed the reference to SQLite from your question as it doesn't make sense in the context. If you're using Firebird, then you're not using SQLite (which is an entirely different database engine).

Comment: Is your field value literally ` 07.04.2022. 11:06:51`, with a dot after 2022?

Comment: do not use `7` and `4` and `'2022-01-01'` and other *literal constants* in the SQL query texts. Your root problem is not that Firebird makes diffewrent text representation of dates than SQLLite, your root problem is polluting query text (code) with data (not code), which opens you to all kinds of fragilities and insecurities (and that error is just one of many manifestations). Use data parameters and pure code-only queries.  http://bobby-tables.com/  see also https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/wiki/SQL-Execution "dynamic parameters binding"

Comment: your column should be of `timestamp` or `date` data type, not any text string,  https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref30/fblangref30-datatypes-datetime.html

Comment: 2022-01-01 is just example. I used class properties instead. Problem was bad syntax. I  wrote it down.

Comment: This is the database that I'm getting from customer. I can not change it. It is what it is.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it, it was a syntax problem. In Firebird, the query needs to look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM SDC_INVOICES si 
INNER JOIN SDC_INVOICES_ITEMS sii ON si.ID = sii.INVOICE_ID
INNER JOIN SDC_INVOICES_TAXES sit ON si.ID = sit.INVOICE_ID
WHERE SUBSTRING (SDC_TIME_SERVER_TIMEZONE FROM 7 FOR 4) || '-' || SUBSTRING (SDC_TIME_SERVER_TIMEZONE FROM 4 FOR 2) || '-' || SUBSTRING (SDC_TIME_SERVER_TIMEZONE FROM 1 FOR 2)
BETWEEN ('2022-04-07') AND ('2022-04-13')
```

Comment: Know that the function `SUBSTRING` is defined in ISO/IEC 9075-2:2016 ("the SQL standard"), so the `SUBSTR` as shown in your question is non-standard.